# Why isn't my image displaying on this webpage?

Tags: php, html, forms

In my program after the user clicks upload, why doesn't the image appear on the page?

Even after I click upload it still says "not working lol". Not sure where I've gone wrong.

upload.php:

```
<html><head><title>PHP Form Upload</title></head><body>

<form method='post' action='upload.php' enctype='multipart'/form-data'>
Select File: <input type='file' name='filename' size'500' />
<input type='submit' value='Upload' />
</form>

<?php
if($_FILES)
{
    $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $name);
    echo "Uploaded image '$name'<br /><img src='$name' />";
}
else echo "not working lol";
?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: else echo "not working lol"; So where are the brackets here?

Comment: I thought you didn't need brackets for a one liner?

Comment: @SakhalTurkaystan no brackets are needed when the code is only one line.

Comment: @winner... I really didn't know so I asked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your html right.

```
+ enctype='multipart'/form-data'
- enctype='multipart/form-data'
```

This would be easier to spot if you did not echo html, like this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Form Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method='post' action='upload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        Select File: <input type='file' name='filename' size'500' />
        <input type='submit' value='Upload' />
    </form>

<?php
    if ($_FILES):
    $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $name);
?>
    Uploaded image <?= $name;?><br /><img src="<?= $name;?>"/>
<?php else: ?>
not working lol
<?php endif;?>
    </body>
</html>
```